# python code does not execute all lines of code in exe file

Tags: python

I have used pyinstaller to convert it but the code does not execute all my lines code in the exe file and cmd ,  but to notice is the original lines code are running perfectly in vs code

i tried py installer  also another named "auto py to exe "
the only thing I want to make the code run in user's windows

```
import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

print("Welcome to the Recharge Assistant")

# Get today's date
today = datetime.date.today()

# Get the same day next year
same_day_next_year = datetime.date(today.year + 1, today.month, today.day)

# Get a valid date from the user
while True:
    user_input = input("Please enter your current validity (DD/MM/YYYY), or 'q' to quit: ")

    # Check if user wants to quit
    if user_input.lower() == 'q':
        break

    try:
        # Convert user's input to a date object
        user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, "%d/%m/%Y").date()

        # Check if user's input is in the past or exceeds the same day next year
        if user_date < today:
            user_date = today
        elif user_date > same_day_next_year:
            user_date = same_day_next_year

        # Calculate the number of days between user_date and same_day_next_year
        DAYS_DIFF = (same_day_next_year - user_date).days
        if DAYS_DIFF == 0:
            print("You may have entered a wrong year or date!")

        # Handle leap year
        if DAYS_DIFF == 366:
            DAYS_DIFF = 365

        # Calculate the number of months and days in days_diff
        months = DAYS_DIFF // 30
        days = DAYS_DIFF % 30

        # Print the updated user date
        print("Current user Validity:", user_date)
        print("Max number of days that can be recharged until next year:", DAYS_DIFF)
        print(f"Number of months that can be recharged: {months} months and {days} days")

        while True:
            try:
                get_month = int(input("How many months do you need? "))
                get_days = get_month * 30
                new_date = user_date + relativedelta(months=get_month)
                print(f"You entered {get_month} months which is {get_days} days.")
                print("The resulting date will be:", new_date)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid date format. Please enter a valid date in the format DD/MM/YYYY.")

    # Add a break statement if the user entered a valid date to allow for quitting
    if user_input.lower() != 'q':
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Never had this problem before, but you should try reinstalling Py and Check if you have missing dependencies that can cause this error.

I suggest $ pip check and even if youre using it or not check your Conda eviroment.

I study your case and hear about you can try to shutdown the console or either set console ==true to false

Comment: hmmm, ,, pip check  :No broken requirements found., the other solution you mentioned , may I don't get you're ideas but will try  , thanks for your quick answer

Comment: i tried to delete "  if user_input.lower() != 'q':
        break   and re executed file with pyinstaller , it doing good now , but how can i break the loop

Comment: Rename DAYS_DIFF to 'days-diff' for python lowercase with underscores case. and check or an invalid user input date compare if the user's date is less than today or greater than the same day next year, it prints an error message and continues to the next iteration of the loop. You should check for more errors in every IF stament because thats probably giving you running errors.

Comment: yes , I Changed it to lower case, and checked all if statement ,nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

After taking another look at this I realized that the problem wasn't the creation of the executable but it was instead how the exceptions were handled. I think that is would be better for you to consider specifically what lines you are expecting to capture an exception at. Here I wrapped the line `user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, "%d/%m/%Y").date()` with the try-except block on its own, so other exceptions being caught elsewhere would not cause this to capture them. I also added a continue keyword to make it continue inside the loop. The program will close immediately when finished, so you should either remove the last if-statement and have the user quit out with "q" as an input, or add a sleep statement to give the user time to see their results.
I built this with `pyinstaller filename.py --onefile` tested it, and it should be working now.

```
import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

print("Welcome to the Recharge Assistant")

# Get today's date
today = datetime.date.today()

# Get the same day next year
same_day_next_year = datetime.date(today.year + 1, today.month, today.day)

# Get a valid date from the user
while True:
    user_input = input("Please enter your current validity (DD/MM/YYYY), or 'q' to quit: ")

    # Check if user wants to quit
    if user_input.lower() == 'q':
        break

    try:
        # Convert user's input to a date object
        user_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid date format. Please enter a valid date in the format DD/MM/YYYY.")
        continue

    # Check if user's input is in the past or exceeds the same day next year
    if user_date < today:
        user_date = today
    elif user_date > same_day_next_year:
        user_date = same_day_next_year

    # Calculate the number of days between user_date and same_day_next_year
    DAYS_DIFF = (same_day_next_year - user_date).days
    if DAYS_DIFF == 0:
        print("You may have entered a wrong year or date!")

    # Handle leap year
    if DAYS_DIFF == 366:
        DAYS_DIFF = 365

    # Calculate the number of months and days in days_diff
    months = DAYS_DIFF // 30
    days = DAYS_DIFF % 30

    # Print the updated user date
    print("Current user Validity:", user_date)
    print("Max number of days that can be recharged until next year:", DAYS_DIFF)
    print(f"Number of months that can be recharged: {months} months and {days} days")

    while True:
        try:
            get_month = int(input("How many months do you need? "))
            get_days = get_month * 30
            new_date = user_date + relativedelta(months=get_month)
            print(f"You entered {get_month} months which is {get_days} days.")
            print("The resulting date will be:", new_date)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")
```

Comment: the first you you say , it works  but only if I deleted the syntax( if user_input.lower())               second one   pyinstaller: error: unrecognized arguments: --ondir   , also when i run the program from cmd its same  , so i see will try to script the code without "break the loop,